# Cannot get d3 svg tutorial to work in jsfiddle

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to [follow a d3 tutorial](http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/#viz3) and [I've created a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/Aks63/2/) for the following code

```
var dataset = [1,2,3,4,5];
var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 75);    

sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("height", 40)
    .attr("width", 75)
    .attr("x", function(d, i){return i*80})
    .attr("y", 20);
```

However, I see the generated circles in the svg but I can't see them on the screen. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v4LHW/1/):

```
var dataset = [1,2,3,4,5];   

sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i){return (i + 1 ) *60})
    .attr("cy", 30)
    .attr("r", 20);
```

I just focused on the main parts that needed change. You can study the differences. Basically, you had the wrong attributes for a circle (x and y, instead of cx and cy) and was missing the radius attribute. Finally, height and width are not circle attributes.